# Android connect to Mysql with C#

Tags: c#, android, mysql

I've been reading on how to acomplish this but everyone uses PHP. AFAIK I've read it's possible to connect to MySql in an Android project using C# but so far I have not found anything useful to acomplish this.

Comment: Android app can't directly connect to Mysql Database on some server. What you can do is to create web services and have your Android app call the web services and consume data from the database.

Comment: There are no client library to use? I need to do this directly, not by a server as the app will be used by Wifi, it's not gonna be available in the play store

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about connecting to MySQL database that is locally hosted or remotely then here is the solution. First you need to add you IP on the server to allow direct connectivity , usually it is done via cPanel Allowed IPs.

```
using System.Data;
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`enter code here`

//this is the part you will need for your method`enter code here`
private void BtnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=yourdomainname.com;Port=3306;database=your_database_name;User Id=yourMySQLuserName;Password=yourpassword;charset=utf8");

    try
    {       
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();         
            txtSysLog.Text = "Successfully connected";   
        }
    } 
    catch(MySqlException ex)
    {
        txtSysLog.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

`txtSysLog` is a text label in the android app. It is used just to show if the connection is done or not.

I recommend using restful web services for more security and not a direct mysql connectivity.